# How to count the highlighted text's characters?

Tags: java, html, string, highlight, jtextarea

I've done some research on the site and I've learned that when using a program that highlights text, wherever I happen to do so, I should use JTextArea or JEditorPane, or even JTextPane. Please just give me some advice as to which I should use to set whatever is highlighted to a String variable **IN JAVA** and which methods I should use.

My Attempt...

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class windowOfCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Count");

        frame.setAlwaysOnTop( true );

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(100,100);

    }
    /*public Object selectionListener() {

    }*/

}
```

Comment: you need show that you have attempted to work on this problem yourself first before just posting a question here....post your current work please

Comment: Do you mean "highlighter" or do you mean "selected"? They have different meanings. Anyway you can search the API for methods that use the above terms. Then if you can ask further questions about a specific method if you still have problems.

Comment: I meant 'selected' I suppose. I looked into TextSelectionManager but under Apache's archives I found it all a bit too ambiguous, at least to perspective of such a novice programmer as myself.